# how to select the hidden element which is not on html in python

Tags: python, google-chrome, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently trying to make the swipe right automation for Tinder. I wanted to select the hidden element which is not on html in python and click it to close the match popup.

my code is

```
def close_match(self):
        is_match_popup_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u-1959572593"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/button').is_displayed()
        try:
            sleep(3)
            #if it is found, click it to close the popup
            if is_match_popup_btn:
                is_match_popup_btn.click()
        except Exception:
            print("Something went wrong in close_match()")
```

I have got xpath of the match popup when I matched on tinder, but it keeps giving me an error on console:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="u-1959572593"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/button"}
```

I know this error means there is no element I want to select because it is not on html, but is there a way to solve this problem?

Things I am using:
`Python 3.7.6`
`chromedriver_mac64`
`chrome=91.0.4472.114`

Comment: Can you share exact tinder url you are working on ?

Comment: this one --> https://tinder.com/app/recs

Comment: What are the steps you want to automate ? I presume that I will have to login and then after

Comment: I want to create program to click the button to close the match popup. Ive got xpath of the button to close, but its element is not on html file.

so steps are like when I see the match popup ->  find out its element ->click the close button